# SQL - 2 table values to be grouped by third unconnected value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, union

I want to create a graph that pulls data from 2 user questions generated from within an SQL database.

The issue is that the user questions are stored in the same table, as are the answers. The only connection is that the question string includes a year value, which I extract using the **LEFT** command so that I output a column called '**YEAR**' with a list of integer values running from 2013 to 2038 (25 year period). 
I then want to pull the corresponding answers ('forecast' and 'actual') from each '**YEAR**' so that I can plot a graph with a couple of values from each year (sorry if this isn't making any sense). The graph should show a forecast line covering the 25 year period with a second line (or column) showing the actual value as it gets populated over the years. I'll then be able to visualise if our actual value is close to our original forecast figures (long term goal!)

**CODE BELOW**

```
SELECT CAST((LEFT(F_TASK_ANS.TA_ANS_QUESTION,4)) AS INTEGER) AS YEAR,
-- first select takes left 4 characters of question and outputs value as string then coverts value to whole number.
CAST((CASE WHEN F_TASK_ANS.TA_ANS_QUESTION LIKE '%forecast' THEN F_TASK_ANS.TA_ANS_ANSWER END) AS NUMERIC(9,2)) AS 'FORECAST',
CAST((CASE WHEN F_TASK_ANS.TA_ANS_QUESTION LIKE '%actual' THEN ISNULL(F_TASK_ANS.TA_ANS_ANSWER,0) END) AS NUMERIC(9,2)) AS 'ACTUAL'
-- actual value will be null until filled in each year therefore ISNULL added to replace null with 0.00.
FROM F_TASK_ANS INNER JOIN F_TASKS ON F_TASK_ANS.TA_ANS_FKEY_TA_SEQ = F_TASKS.TA_SEQ
WHERE TA_ANS_ANSWER <> ''
AND (TA_TASK_ID LIKE '%6051' OR TA_TASK_ID LIKE '%6052')
-- The two numbers above refer to separate PPM questions that the user enters a value into
```

I tried **GROUP BY 'YEAR'** but I get an

> Error: Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that
>   is not an outer reference - which I assume is because I haven't linked
>   the 2 tables in any way...

Should I be adding a **UNION** so the tables are joined?

What I want to see is something like the following output (which I'll graph up later)

```
YEAR    FORECAST    ACTUAL
2013    135000      127331
2014    143000      145102
2015    149000           0
2016    158000           0
2017    161000           0
2018... etc
```

Any help or guidance would be hugely appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Which SQL database is this in?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 (hosted by third party)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the syntax is pretty hairy, this seems like a fairly simple query.  You are in fact linking your two tables (with the JOIN statement) and you don't need a UNION.

Try something like this (using a common table expression, or CTE, to make the grouping clearer, and changing the syntax for slightly greater clarity):

```
 WITH  data
 AS  (
    SELECT YEAR = CAST((LEFT(A.TA_ANS_QUESTION,4)) AS INTEGER)
       ,   FORECAST = CASE WHEN A.TA_ANS_QUESTION LIKE '%forecast' 
                           THEN CONVERT(NUMERIC(9,2), A.TA_ANS_ANSWER)
                           ELSE CONVERT(NUMERIC(9,2), 0)
                      END
       ,   ACTUAL = CASE WHEN A.TA_ANS_QUESTION LIKE '%actual' 
                         THEN CONVERT(NUMERIC(9,2), ISNULL(A.TA_ANS_ANSWER,0) )
                         ELSE CONVERT(NUMERIC(9,2), 0)
                    END
    FROM F_TASK_ANS A
       INNER JOIN F_TASKS T
           ON A.TA_ANS_FKEY_TA_SEQ = T.TA_SEQ
    -- It sounded like you wanted to include the ones where the answer was null.  If 
    -- that's wrong, get rid of the test for NULL.
    WHERE (A.TA_ANS_ANSWER <> '' OR A.TA_ANS_ANSWER IS NULL) 
      AND (TA_TASK_ID LIKE '%6051' OR TA_TASK_ID LIKE '%6052')
  )
  SELECT     YEAR
       ,     FORECAST = SUM(data.Forecast)
       ,     ACTUAL = SUM(data.Actual)
  FROM       data
  GROUP BY   YEAR
  ORDER BY   YEAR
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your help, unfortunately it just generates an error (with no reference as to why) so I can't confirm if it's working as I need. I am not knowledgeable enough to work out what might be causing the failure. Sorry.

Comment: @GaryGibson  What error is it?  The conversion error you mention elsewhere?

Comment: Sorry Ann, the screen was just blanking with a preset error screen saying contact your administrator (hosted system!).

Comment: Just tried again and it is now coming up with the SQL Error: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '664900.53' to data type int. The value is entered by users as a number as it's a financial value. Where is it trying to convert to an integer?

Comment: @GaryGibson Gotcha. I just did some tests, and based on those I think I know where the error is occurring.  It's happening because all the THEN and ELSE clauses in the CASE ... END statement have to return values of the same type. So it tries to convert `TA_ANS_ANSWER` to integer (to match the `0`) and fails.  I've reworked that part to accommodate that.

Comment: Ann! Worked perfectly, amazing stuff!. I've tried to follow your method and think I can just about follow. Many, many thanks for your time an effort. Gary

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this ...

```
SELECT CAST((LEFT(F_TASK_ANS.TA_ANS_QUESTION,4)) AS INT) AS [YEAR]

      ,SUM(CAST((CASE WHEN F_TASK_ANS.TA_ANS_QUESTION LIKE '%forecast' 
        THEN F_TASK_ANS.TA_ANS_ANSWER ELSE 0 END) AS NUMERIC(9,2))) AS [FORECAST]

     ,SUM(CAST((CASE WHEN F_TASK_ANS.TA_ANS_QUESTION LIKE '%actual'  
       THEN F_TASK_ANS.TA_ANS_ANSWER  ELSE 0 END) AS NUMERIC(9,2))) AS [ACTUAL]

FROM F_TASK_ANS INNER JOIN F_TASKS 
ON F_TASK_ANS.TA_ANS_FKEY_TA_SEQ = F_TASKS.TA_SEQ
WHERE TA_ANS_ANSWER <> ''
AND (TA_TASK_ID LIKE '%6051' OR TA_TASK_ID LIKE '%6052')
GROUP BY CAST((LEFT(F_TASK_ANS.TA_ANS_QUESTION,4)) AS INT)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I can't work out why but it returns the following SQL Error: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '664900.53' to data type int. I can't see where that conversion is happening. The value is entered by users as a decimal (financial value).

Comment: Many thanks for your help M.Ali, much appreciated but on this occasion someone else provided the perfect solution. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Not a problem glad you have found the solution :)